# c create file in terminal using freopen and argv[1]

Tags: c, pointers, terminal

I'm trying to create a file using terminal in Unix. My code is below. I know for a fact argv[1] is picking up the data from the terminal screen, so for example when i do ./a.out newfile.txt, argv[1] has the value newfile.txt

When I run the command ls to check my directory, the file is called argv[1]. Do i need to use some form of pointers to succeed in what I'm attempting?

Regards

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("File to create: %s \n", argv[1] );
  freopen("argv[1]", "w+", stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value from `freopen()` so you know whether it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling `freopen` to create a file called `"argv[1]"`, as a `char*` (as a "string" if you will). To actually use the `argv[1]` argument to create a file as per the first argument given to your program, don't quote the argv[1]:

```
  freopen(argv[1], "w+", stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove quotes.

```
freopen(argv[1], "w+", stdout);
```